# Is there a way to remove the switch users Icon without root?

Tags: adb, settings, multi-user

I have a Verzon Moto E2 (so no hope of rooting) on android 5.1.

I think you cannot completely disable it without root.

I'd like to at least remove the little icon in the pull down menu. is that possible using ADB **without** root?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I cannot root, as Verizon locked the bootloader

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately is impossible without root.

You can however Root and if you have any problem that need go to fix it, you can Unroot the phone.

Comment: Can you share the way utilizing root access (even if you've not tested it yourself)? That would be very nice.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot root this Verizon phone...